# Do well with something

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "do well with something" to mean "someone is getting better at something"?

For example:

A person doesn't follow rules, but he tries hard and begins following the rules.

So he asks:

Am I doing well with rules?

Does this mean that the person is getting better at following the rules,or he's started following rules?

And if a person is not good at something but starts learning it and asks:

Am I doing well with crafting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

> I am doing better with rules.

or more generally:

> I am doing better with/at X-ing/X."

is perfectly idiomatic informal English.

A slightly more formal way of saying this is:

> I am *getting* better at following rules.

or

> I am *getting* better at X-ing.

or

> I am *getting* better at Y-ing X.

(e.g. "following rules", "correcting errors"

Comment: And what about: Doing well with rules?

Comment: For the sentences with 'doing', 'well' works just as well. 'well' does not work with 'getting'